# Why is the Laplace Transformation defined the way it is?

Tags: laplace-transform

I can see the many uses of Laplace Transformation, but why is it defined the way it is? What is its physical significance?

Comment: Did you try computing the "modified Laplace" transform of anything, like $f(t) = 1$?

Comment: If you put that minus sign, it will help the integral converge.

Comment: @ T. Bongers No I did not, but I see what you mean. I still do not understand its physical significance however.

Comment: What would you prefer?

Comment: This [Youtube lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvbdoSeGAgI) helps to explain mathematically why it is defined as it is. Not sure what, if any, physical significance it has. The Fourier transform (a special case) does have physical significance, for example one can take a Fourier transform [using an optical lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_optics#Fourier_transforming_property_of_lenses)